# I want to redirect /folder/subfolder to /folder

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a page at mydomain.com/channels/somename which displays that specific page (that folder actually exists). I want what i display there to show up when i navigate to mydomain.com/somename

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Well i tried #RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ channels/$1 and that redirected mydomain.com/xxx to channels/xxx but that is not what i needed as need to show the content at channels/xxxx at mydomain.com/xxx .... whats up with people down voting a question liek this btw lol. So strange hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to the `.htaccess` file in your web document root folder (often `public_html` or `htdocs`):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ channels/$1  [L]
```

This assumes that mod_rewrite is **both** installed **and** activated for htaccess files. 
If you are not sure, to check if mod_rewrite is installed, look at the list of installed modules in the output of `phpinfo();`
By default, mod_rewrite is not enabled for htaccess files. If you are managing your own server, open `httpd.conf`
and make sure that the webroot directory block contains one of these lines: `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOverride All`

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, i tried it and it didnt work out. What happened was it now redirects to to channels/xxx when i go to mydomain.com/xxx ... but what i want to see happen is at mydomain.com/xxx the content of /channels/xxx is shown.

Comment: Updated the answer, try again. The redirect is internal, so the content of `/channels/xxx` whould be shown, while the address remains `mydomain.com/xxx` Do not add `R` or `R=301` with the `[L]` as that will cause the address to change in the browser.

Comment: Hi, thx again. Sadly it still went to channels/xxx in the url when i navigated to mydomain.com/xxx. To test i cleared anything what was in the htaccess in the root and just added the part you said to add. Mod rewrite is installed and working btw ;)

Comment: That doesn't sound right, are you sure you have just `[L]`? Can you try in a different browser? Maybe a cache interference.

Comment: I indeed tried it in other browsers and have the [L] like in your example. So weird cause it feels like such a simple thing but man it gives me a headache hehe. Also a hard-one to search for in google cause most just talk about redirecting the URL root to some sub folder .. sigh ;)

Comment: Hmm very strange i just tried some things again and wound up just using it like this RewriteRule    ^([^/.]+)/?$ channels/$1/ [L]  and then it seemed to work. Thx again :)